# Magento 2 proper way to do ajax call?

Tags: php, ajax, magento2

This is my controller:

namespace Mvp\Mercury\Controller\Index;

```
class Display extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

protected $resultJsonFactory;

public function __construct(
    Context                                             $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory    $resultJsonFactory
) {

    $this->resultJsonFactory            = $resultJsonFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}


public function execute()
{
    $result                 = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
    if ($this->getRequest()->isAjax())) 
    {
        $test=Array
        (
            'Firstname' => 'What is your firstname',
            'Email' => 'What is your emailId',
            'Lastname' => 'What is your lastname',
            'Country' => 'Your Country'
        );
        return $result->setData($test);
    }
}
```

}

I´m making a ajax call to this controller however gives me error , i´m trying it this way:

```
function addItemToShoppingCart(data)
{
console.log("You are about to add part: " + data.productNumber + " with qty: " + data.quantity + " and price: " + data.price);

var sku        = data.productNumber,
   qty        = data.quantity,
   price      = data.price,
   base_url   = '<?php echo $this->getUrl(); ?>',
   module_url = 'helloworld/index/display',
   full_url   = base_url + module_url;

var cart_info = {
    sku : sku,
    qty : qty,
    price: price
};

console.log(full_url);
console.log(cart_info);

$.ajax({
    showLoader: true,
    url: full_url,
    data: cart_info,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function (data) {

    console.log('success');

});
}
```

based on that i don´t know why it gives me error, the exact code it gives is 500, i checked permissions and they have everything, so what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

500 error doesn't occur due to permission. If the problem was with permission then it would have shown 403 error. 500 error comes when the code has some error. Try to check error log or set deploy mode: developer by running following command:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Now, you will be able to see exact error. Now you can solve it or if you face problem, paste the error here.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Mvp\\Mercury\\Controller\\Index\\Display::__construct() must be an instance of Mvp\\Mercury\\Controller\\Index\\Context, instance of Magento\\Framework\\App\\Action\\Context given

Comment: Inject *\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context* in your controller before any other class as shown here:

`public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
)
{
    return parent::__construct($context);
}`

After this, clear contents of *var/generation/Mvp* and try to run again.. hope it will work. If you find my answer helpful, please upvote.

Comment: for now, you are just using *Context*, thats why its tryng to search this class in current namespace i.e.  Mvp\Mercury\Controller\Index